# How to exclude unrelated search results from django-haystack and Elasticsearch?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, django-haystack

I'm trying to search for products based on their keywords. My `haystack` index is as follows:

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    name= indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True) # contains keywords associated with the product
```

In this case, the field "text" contains a group of keywords associated with the product. For instance, here is a sample product index:

```
name: "Tide Detergent"
text: "laundry household shopping cleaning supplies"
```

When I search for `laundry`, `Tide Detergent` appears on the search, but so do other irrelevant results, such as products that have `lawn` or `laugh` in the `text`. So it looks like `elasticsearch` is searching not just for `laundry` but variations of the word also.

Here is what my search query looks like:

```
qs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(content__exact='laundry')
```

My question is: how can I force `haystack` or `elasticsearch` to search strictly for my input keyword and ignore variations of them? In other words, how can ensure that haystack searches for only `laundry` and exclude any other terms?

Comment: It seems to be that django haystack is suitable for simple use cases and has poor API for doing anything smart with a search. I'm looking forward to django-elasticsearch-dsl
https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I used a raw `elasticsearch` query instead of going directly through `haystack`. In that query, I used a `constant_score` query which will search for *exact* terms, not fuzzy terms in addition.

```
{
    "query":{
        "query":{
            "constant_score":{
                "filter":{
                    "bool":{
                        "must":[
                            {"bool":{
                                    "must":[
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "text":"laundry"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's more info about the `constant_score` query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html